# Docker NGINX Image lin to custom 404 page

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

Hey there I know how to do a 404 page in NGINX but when using docker I can't get it working does someone has an idea how to map a 404.html as custom 404 page in docker NGINX image? I use this image: https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/ and want to do something like this:

`error_page 404 /404.html;`
and redirect non www to www I come from apache and need NGINX for a small project.

But can't find a solution online hope someone knows how to get it working.

I tried to do

```
docker exec -it <NGINXcontainerID> bash
```

and then I did `nano nginx.conf`

and pasted this code:

```
error_page 404 /error_404.html; #custom 404 page
```

after that I did

```
service nginx restart
exit (exit from container)
```

and (on host server)

```
docker restart <NGINX container ID>
```

This did not work hope someone has an idea

thanks

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal verifiable complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: sure will edit in a second

Comment: added now code example :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your approach is that docker when you exit the container will reset to initial state. In order to persist your state, you need to create a conf file locally on your machine and mount it via 
`docker -v <host path to conf>:<guest path to conf> //rest of your commands`